# Unable to deploy image due to authorisation

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have a simple node app that has a Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

This file builds and runs fine locally.

Trying to push it as an image to a GitHub registry as follows via `Github Actions`.

Note that I have set up the secrets values as `repository secrets` under actions in my repository.

```
name: Deploy to Production

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.0.0

      - name: Set up Docker
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2.10.0

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.2.1
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: docker.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository }}/app:${{ github.sha }}
          build-args: |
            NODE_VERSION=20
```

It fails at the `Build and push Docker image` stage with follow error:

> ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push
> docker.pkg.github.com/***/reponame/app:6e999cfdacd6dc6b0a0b1e910a5df587ff0e29d0:
> unexpected status from HEAD request to
> https://docker.pkg.github.com/v2/***/reponame/app/blobs/sha256:b57f8774f8f3f8e4585beb859bb784b1cb1e558b851438ee332890b5f39f5aee:
> 401 Unauthorized Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve:
> failed to push
> docker.pkg.github.com/***/reponame/app:6e999cfdacd6dc6b0a0b1e910a5df587ff0e29d0:
> unexpected status from HEAD request to
> https://docker.pkg.github.com/v2/***/reponame/app/blobs/sha256:b57f8774f8f3f8e4585beb859bb784b1cb1e558b851438ee332890b5f39f5aee:
> 401 Unauthorized

Why, what authorization am I missing?

Comment: `docker.pkg.github.com` seems to be the GitHub registry, not the DockerHub registry

Comment: @MarcoCaberletti You are right, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

*"401 Unauthorized Error"* => I would go for a problem with :

```
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Are you sure they are correct?